# Mongoengine, how to get last element in listField

Tags: mongoengine, listfield

The familiar pythonic slicing conventions of `myList[-1:][0]` and `myList[-1]` are not available for Mongoengine listFields because it does not support negative indices. Is there an elegant way to get the last element of a list?

Error verbiage for posterity:

> `IndexError: Cursor instances do not support negative indices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the last item with this code:

```
myList[len(myList) - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `len` on a QuerySet, because this will evaluate the query set. Django docs:

> A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you might
>   expect, returns the length of the result list.

If you just want to get the length of the set use `count` instead. So answering your question, I would use something like `myList[myList.count() - 1]`.